# Injecting JSF bean into Spring bean - impossible?

Tags: spring, jsf, dependency-injection

I have a JSF 2.0 bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable
{
    protected String name;

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    //....
}
```

I have a Spring 3.0 bean:

```
@Repository
public class Logins
{
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{loginBean}")
    protected LoginBean loginBean;

    public void recordLogin()
    {
         //... record in db that loginBean.getName() just logged in
    }
}
```

This code doesn't work, Logins.loginBean is never set.

Alternatively (its the same question, simplified) - would the following code ever work?

```
@Repository
public class SpringBean
{
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{session.id}")
    protected String id;

    //....
}
```

The ContextLoaderListener and RequestLoaderListener are declared in web.xml.

Is it possible at all to inject a JSF bean into a Spring bean? (Without using yet another extra framework)

Or should I rather convert my JSF bean into a Spring bean and use the DelegatingVariableResolver trick in faces-config.xml? I have already tested this with a test Spring bean, and it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using JSF annotations in spring-managed beans doesn't work. And it shouldn't - you should not inject things from the web layer in the other layers. It should be the other way around - inject spring services (or repositories) into web components (jsf managed beans), and invoke methods on them, passing the managed bean properties as arguments

Comment: Thank you, this confirms what I already suspected after googling for an hour without success :) My initial thought was to convert LoginBean to a Spring bean, but you're right about not injecting from the web layer. So I will inject the Spring "Logins" into the JSF "LoginBean".